# Why is the  $L_p$ norm strictly convex for $1<p<\infty?$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $x,y \in L_p$   such that  $\|x\|_p=\|y\|_p=1$ , $1< p<\infty$ and $x\neq y.$
Why is $\|x+y\|_p<2$  ?

I'm not sure how to start the proof.. I don't know how to handle integral of $(x+y)^p$ and it seems that using the binomial theorem won't be a great success.

Comment: Start using the proof of the triangle inequality, and look at the equality case in Hölder inequality (you may have to use the strict convexity of the exponential).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Minkowski's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) gives $ \| x+y \|_p \leq \|x\|_p + \| y \|_p = 2 $ with equality if and  only if $x$ and $y$ are positively linearly dependent (i.e. $x=ty$ or $y=tx$ for some $t\geq 0$).

If $x$ and $y$ were positively linearly dependent, say $x=ty$, then plugging into $\|x\|_p=\|y\|_p=1$ forces $t=1$ so $x=y$, which contradicts the assumption $ x\neq y.$ Thus we do not reach the equality case, so $\| x+y \|_p <2. $

Comment: Does this also hold in the complex case?

Comment: @warm_fish Yes.