Linear Analysis – Examples 1-Q5 General $l^p$ spaces vs $l^1, l^\infty$
Let $1<p<\infty$, and let $x$ and $y$ be vectors in $l_p$ with $\left \|x  \right \|=\left \|y  \right \|=1$ and $\left \|x +y \right \|=2$, how to prove $x=y$?
I know how to prove for $p=2$ using paralleogram law, but for $p\neq 2$, $l_p$ has no inner product, so I don't know how to prove those cases.
I know this is not true for $l^1$ and $l^\infty$, I would be grateful if you could give me a hint on the difference between general $l^p$ and these two spaces which could help me come up with a solution myself.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80139/why-is-the-l-p-norm-strictly-convex-for-1p-infty

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Like we can use Minkowski equality case for $L^p$ as if $l^p$  is $L^p$ space with some weird measure which turns integral into sum?

@HIH Yes, one can. Namely, we consider $L^p(\mathbb{N}, dm)$ where $dm$ is the counting measure (i.e. $dm(S)$ is the cardinality of $S$). Then we get for $f\in L^p(\mathbb{N}, dm)$ $$ \int_{\mathbb{N}} \vert f(n) \vert^p dm(n)= \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \vert f(n) \vert^p. $$ Thus, we can identify $L^p(\mathbb{N}, dm)$ and $\ell^p(\mathbb{N})$.

It is actually an equality. Simply because a sequence is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to the space of where your coefficients live.

If you are looking for a more general class of spaces with the property you describe, you can google uniformly convex spaces. The Milman-Pettis theorem is telling us that every uniformly convex Banach space is reflexive (i.e. the map $X\rightarrow X^{**}, x \mapsto (\varphi\mapsto \varphi(x))$ is an isomorphism of Banach spaces). However, $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty$ are not reflexive. One could say that the underlying geometry of the space is very different for $p\in {1,\infty}$.
